# Property of homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have this proposition, and I have two questions:

1) Why $H_k=\text{Im} i_*\oplus \ker r_*$ ?

2) Why $j_*: \ker r_*\rightarrow H_k(X,A)$ ?

[image]

Edit:

For the second, I try the 1th theorem of isomorphism, and I found that there is an isomorphism between $H_k(X)/\ker j∗$ and $H_k(X,A)$, and I don't know how to appear $\ker r∗$ in the place of $H_k(X)/\ker j∗$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of a result of homological algebra which is:
If  $0\to N\stackrel{i}{\to} M\stackrel{j}\to P\to 0$ is an exact sequence and $r:M\to N$  such that $r\circ i=id_{N}$ then $\ker r\simeq P$ and $\text{Im}(i)\simeq N$, and $M=\text{Im}(i)\oplus \ker r \simeq N\oplus P$. 
**Proof:**
Because $i$ is injective we have $\text{Im}(i)\simeq N$.
For $\ker r \simeq P$ it suffice to show that $j:\ker r\to P$ is an isomorphism: if $x\in \ker r$ such that $j(x)=0$ then $x\text{Im}(i)$ hence there exists $y\in N$ such that $x=i(y)$, but $y=r(i(y))=r(x)=0$. for the surjectivity, let $z\in P$, there exists $x\in M$ such that $y=j(x)$ set $x'=i(r(x))$, we have $r(x-x')=r(x)-r(i(r(x)))=r(x)-r(x)=0$, hence $x-x'\in \ker r$ and $j(x-x')=j(x)-j(i(r(x)))=j(x)=z$.
For $M=\text{Im}(i)\oplus \ker r$: let $y\in \text{Im}(i)\cap \ker r$ then there exists $x\in N$ such that $y=i(x)$ , sa $0=r(y)=r(i(x))=x$ we have $y=i(x)=i(0)=0$.
Let $y\in M$, and set $x=r(y)$, we have $x=i(r(y))\in \text{Im}(i)$ we have 
$r(y-x)=r(y)-r(i(r(y)))=r(y)-r(y)=0$, then $z=y-x\in \ker r$, now we get 
$yx+z$ with $x\in \text{Im}(i)$ and $z\in \ker r$.

Comment: Merci @Hamou, svp pour quoi on ne peut pas dire directement que $H_k(X)=\text{Im} r_*\oplus \ker r_*$ ?

Comment: Normalement on peut dire n'importe quoi, mais c'est la façon de dire qui compte: c-a-d on peut le dire intuitivement ou d'après un autre résultat bien connue , ou sans dimenstrasion .........

Comment: Est que c'est vrai que $H_k(X)=\text{Im} r_*\oplus \ker r_*$ ou c'est faux ? Merci beaucoup

Comment: yes it is true.

Comment: Ok, c'est une autre méthode et svp toute fonction $f: X\rightarrow Y$ injective verifie $\text{Im}~f=X$ ? merci

Comment: Attention, l'image de $f$ est une partie de $Y$ et non pas de $X$!

Comment: oui et donc pourquoi $\text{im}~i_*=H_k(A)$?

Comment: Si $f:N\to M $ est injective alors $N\simeq \text{Im(f)}$. en effet c'est un isomorphism.

Comment: je pense que ceci est vrai uniquement si $N\subset M$ ?

Comment: Sauf si je dit que $N=\text{Im}~f\oplus \ker f$ comme $f$ est injective $\ker f=\lbrace 0\rbrace$ et donc $N=\text{Im}~f$ qu'on dite vous ?

Comment: $N$ et $M$ deux modules, et $f:N\to M$ une application linéaire injective. $N'=\text{Im}(f)$ est un sous mudule de $M$, alors les deux modules $N$ et $N'$ sont isomoephe. mais il n y a aucune hypothèse que $N$ soit un sous module de $M$. mais on écrit $N\simeq N'$.

Comment: ou est ce que je peux trouver cette propriété je ne la connait pas

Comment: Je suis bete sorry on utilise le premier theorem d'isomorphisme that's all, $N/\ker f \simeq \text{Im}~f $ $f$ est injective donc $\ker f=\lbrace 0\rbrace $

Comment: Mais svp j'ai oublier $i_*$ est injective parce que cette une inclusion ?

Comment: je suis désolé, mais j'ai lu la réponse donné par Zach pouvez vous m’expliquer cette phrase "The same idea lets you write things in split short exact sequences as sums"

Comment: un coup d'oeil: [Suites exactes courtes scindées](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_exacte)

Comment: Oui mais que veut il dire ? il faut rendre tout les espaces en somme directe ? et la suite exacte courte vient uniquement du fait que $i_*$ est injective ?merci

Comment: rendre l'espace situé au milieux (de la suite) en somme direct. Mais a condition que la suite court soit **exacte et scindée**

Comment: s'il vous plait etes vous sure que $i_*$ est injective prcequ'elle est induite par une inclusion ? merci

Comment: Si $f\circ g=id$ alors $g$ est injective. Dans votre cas vous avez $r_*\circ i_*=id_{H_k(A)}$ donc $i_*$ est injective.

Comment: pouvez vous me dire pourquoi $f\circ g =id $ alors g est injective, je ne vois pas comment faire merci

Comment: Avce cette hypothèse cad $f\circ g=id$, si $g(x)=g(y)$ alors $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$ donc $x=f(g(x))=f(g(y))=y$ i.e $x=y$.

Comment: merci donc le fait que i soit une inclusion n'a rien a avoir avec l'injectivité

Comment: Oui, mais inclusion+retraction= ca marche.

Comment: comment ? s'il vous plait ?

Comment: Si $r$ est une retraction alors $r\circ i=id$ donc $r_*\circ i_*=id$ ansi $i_*$ est injective.

Comment: S'il vous plait, vous pouvez m'aider  ici, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913379/question-about-property-of-homology  d'ou viens la somme directe j'ai pas d'idée svp svp

Comment: please svp aidez moi

Answer (score 1):

The trick to do (1) goes like this. If you have $x \in H_k(X)$, you apply $ir$ to get $ir(x) \in im i_*$. The cool thing is than you can then just check that $x - irx$ is in the kernel of $r$, and so $x = irx + (x - irx)$ is your decomposition. To show it's direct, you take $0 = iy + z$. Then applying $r$, we get $0 = riy = y$, and so the sum is direct. The same idea lets you write things in split short exact sequences as sums.

For (2), using your observation from the first isomorphism theorem you put in the edit:
\begin{align*}
H_k(X,A) &\cong H_k(X)/(\ker j_*) \\
&= (\ker r_* \oplus im i_*)/(\ker j_*) \\
&= (\ker r_* \oplus \ker j_*)/(\ker j_*) \\
&= \ker r_* \end{align*} Note where we used the exactness condition $im i_* = \ker j_*$.

Comment: I dont understand "The same idea lets you write things in split short exact sequences as sums" ? please need your help

Comment: please how to do to obtain this short exacte sequence

Comment: There's a theorem in homological algebra that says a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ of abelian groups that has a map $r:B \rightarrow A$ which, when composed with $A \rightarrow B$, gives the identity on $A$ induces a direct sum decomposition of $B$ as $B \cong A \oplus C$. The way that you prove this is similar to the arguments I gave. You could, in fact, directly apply this to obtain the proposition in your question.